# python pandas plot.bar something wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

```
mpg['grade'] = np.where(mpg['total'] >= 30, 'A', np.where(mpg['total'] >= 20, 'B', 'C'))
```

code 1)

```
count_grade = mpg['grade'].value_counts()
count_grade.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()
```

code 2)

```
count_grade = mpg['grade'].value_counts().sort_index() # method chaining
count_grade.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()
```

reference) count_grade -> 'A' : 10, 'B' : 118, 'C' : 106

**(in VSCode)**
The execution result is different with and without the code 1).
When I only run code 2) without code 1), A is more than 120 instead of 10 (in graph)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRHEp.png)
However, when the two codes are executed together, the result is normally output as a result of only 'A', 'B', and 'C' being sorted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxG6B.png)

**(in Colab)**

```
mpg['grade'] = np.where(mpg['total'] >= 30, 'A', np.where(mpg['total'] >=20, 'B', 'C'))
count_grade = mpg['grade'].value_counts().sort_index()
print(count_grade)
count_grade.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

When I put this code in one block and run it, the results are output strangely.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLC1Z.png)

However, running the last line separately solves the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMFDI.png)

I'd like to know what the problem is. please help me

expecting : [image]
but my result : [image]

**mpg.head().to_dict()**

```
model': {0: 'a4', 1: 'a4', 2: 'a4', 3: 'a4', 4: 'a4'}, 'displ': {0: 1.8, 1: 1.8, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 2.8}, 'year': {0: 1999, 1: 1999, 2: 2008, 3: 2008, 4: 1999}, 'cyl': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 6}, 'trans': {0: 'auto(l5)', 1: 'manual(m5)', 2: 'manual(m6)', 3: 'auto(av)', 4: 'auto(l5)'}, 'drv': {0: 'f', 1: 'f', 2: 'f', 3: 'f', 4: 'f'}, 'cty': {0: 18, 1: 21, 2: 20, 3: 21, 4: 16}, 'hwy': {0: 29, 1: 29, 2: 31, 3: 30, 4: 26}, 'fl': {0: 'p', 1: 'p', 2: 'p', 3: 'p', 4: 'p'}, 'category': {0: 'compact', 1: 'compact', 2: 'compact', 3: 'compact', 4: 'compact'}, 'total': {0: 23.5, 1: 25.0, 2: 25.5, 3: 25.5, 4: 21.0}, 'grade': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'}}
```

** my full code **

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpg = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv')
mpg['total'] = (mpg['cty'] + mpg['hwy']) / 2

mpg['grade'] = np.where(mpg['total'] >= 30, 'A', np.where(mpg['total'] >= 20, 'B', 'C'))
count_grade = mpg['grade'].value_counts()
count_grade.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()

count_grade = mpg['grade'].value_counts().sort_index()
count_grade.plot.bar(rot=0)
print(count_grade)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please share a [mre]. Add a dummy sample of your `mpg` as text in a code block: try something like `mpg.head().to_dict()` and post between triple backticks (```). Also show the results of running your different code combinations on *that particular* sample. Your supposed incorrect plots have a y-label called "Frequency", what is this? You're not sharing any code that should normally produce a plot with that label.

Comment: hi! thank you for comment!! I edited the post adding mpg.head().to_dict(), my full code! "Frequency" is automatically generated ylabel. (count_grade.plot.bar())
count_grade -> 'A' : 10, 'B' : 118, 'C' : 106

Comment: *However, running the last line separately solves the problem* ... Please describe what running last line separately means. Outside of any IDE, what is result of your code when running at command line using `python /path/to/myscript.py`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no actual question here. Check out [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title ­— that might be something like "Why is .plot.bar showing different results depending on other code I run?"

Comment: @garlicman This isn't a [mre]. Firstly the syntax is invalid, but that just seems like a copy-paste error. More importantly, `mpg['grade'].value_counts()` with this data is just `B 5`; @ouroboros1 already mentioned this: "... running your different code combinations on *that particular* sample". But if all you need to reproduce the problem is the value counts, just provide that: `count_grade = pd.Series({'A': 10, 'B': 118, 'C': 106}, name='count').rename_axis('grade')`